# Simlpe Loops in Topological Graph

Tags: general-topology, graph-theory

Given a set of points in 3D space, and a set of links between them which form a connected graph - is there a general strategy for extracting all simple loops from such an object?

I refer to simple loops as being those cycles in the graph which have no other edges on, or vertices intersecting with, the surface enclosed by the loop.

Comment: Presumably you have some notion of "the surface enclosed by the loop" - there are infinitely many surfaces with boundary a given loop, so you need to specify how you're picking one. Maybe https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_surface is useful?

Answer (score 1):

That's not really well-defined.

Suppose that $T$ is a (hollow) triangle in the xy-plane enclosing the origin, and $S$ is the vertical segment from $(0,0,-1)$ to $(0,0,1)$. Add in a line segment from $(0,0,1)$ to some vertex of $T$, and call that your connected graph $G$.

Is the triangle $T$ a simple loop? Well, one surface that it enclosed is the filled triangle in the xy-plane, which meets $S$. But you an also say it encloses a triangle (topologically) that "sags down" beneath the edge $S$. Since you talked about a "topological graph," I'm assuming that topological disks are allowed.

Furthermore, not every loop encloses just one surface. Consider an ordinary torus $T$, and draw a small disk $D$ on the torus, with boundary some (near-)circle  $S$. Then $S$ bounds the disk, but it's also the boundary of $T - D$.

It might be tempting to say "well, I meant the *disk* enclosed by the loop," but if you consider a polygonal approximation of a trefoil knot, you have a loop that does indeed bound a surface (indeed, it bounds both an orientable and a nonorientable surface, and in fact many of each kind), but it does not bound an embedded disk.

In short: the answer is "there's no simple strategy for doing this, because the problem's ill-defined.

Comment: I see. Well my problem is that I would like to determine the distribution of the "hole" sizes in a 3D object of which I have the graph description. My object forms a single connected component and looks similar to a termite gallery network. I would like to extract the cycles in this graph whose boundaries do not have other edges enclosed. (Sorry for my non-technical description)

Comment: Well, as my answer shows, that's not really well-defined. But you might find Edelsbrunner's work on "persistent homology" would be useful in characterising the distribution of hole sizes in some way.